# Simple statistics on live time series

Tags: statistics

I have a process getting a numeric data every minute. Here's an example:

```
2015/03/05 17:51, 708
2015/03/05 17:52, 438
2015/03/05 17:53, 444
2015/03/05 17:54, 444
2015/03/05 17:55, 450
2015/03/05 17:56, 450
2015/03/05 17:57, 408
2015/03/05 17:58, 408
2015/03/05 17:59, 414
```

I would like to, for instance,

- Plot 24h and the respective averages;
- Check highest and lowest amount on a given period (month, week, free period);

Which software (preferably simple) do you recommend for me to process basic stats on this data?

Comment: This question is off-topic here and IMHO should be migrated to the Software Recommendations SE site. However, check [my relevant answer](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/3723/2452) - I hope that you will find it useful.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for software recommendations.

Comment: It would help if you added some details. Do you want it to be free or Open Source. What Operating systems (e.g. Windows, Mac, Linux) should it support? Etc.

Comment: For what operating system? What format do you want the output in?

Comment: I'm using Mac and the tool should be open source (or free for personal use). As for the output, I don't need it in special format (pdf, jpg) or medium (web, or in-app). I just need to visualize it. @AleksandrBlekh your answer is quite thorough so I will try some of the tools

Comment: Sounds good. Good luck and keep us posted what worked well for you.